# Erlang Error Handling , X unsafe in 'try'

Tags: erlang, try-catch

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this bit of code spits back that the X is unsafe in 'try', well I know why, but more so how to fix it.

```
try X = lists:append(lists:zipwith3(fun(X, Y, Z) -> [X, Y, Z] end, Data1, Data2, Data3)) of
            MP -> X
            catch K -> (X = 0)
            end.
            %MP = [lists:zipwith3(X, Y, Z) || X, Y, Z <-  [Data1, Data2, Data3]],


P = X
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to fix it is to put the assignment outside of the try-catch:

```
X =
    try lists:append(lists:zipwith3(fun(X, Y, Z) -> [X, Y, Z] end, Data1, Data2, Data3)) of
        MP -> MP
    catch K -> 0
    end.
```

As for why this happens, the [chapter on expressions in the Erlang reference manual](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#variables) says:

> For the `try` expression variable scoping is limited so that variables bound in the expression are always 'unsafe' outside the expression.

It used to say "This is to be improved", but that was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/14de5449503).

Answer (score 1):

It is unsafe I believe due to the fact that you do not cover all the exceptions.
When you have

```
catch K -> (X = 0)
```

I believe it'll only catch thrown exceptions, there are still errors, and exits. IIRC
so you will probably need

```
catch _:K -> (X=0)
```

or explicitly catch them as

```
catch 
  error:K -> (X=0);
  exit:K -> (X=0);
  throw:K -> (X=0)
```

(I'm not 100% that I have the atom names correct, but the idea is still the same)